# how to destroy a $.animate function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have some code like this:

```
function updateCounter(){
  $({someValue: 2*60*1000}).animate({someValue: 0}, {
      duration: 2*60*1000,
      easing:"linear",
      step: function() {
        //dosomething
      },
      complete: function() {
        // 2 minutes end
        alert('game_over');
      }
    });
}
```

Normally the `game over` will be alerted after 2 mins. But what if I want to kill the counter before it ends? I have an idea of something like this: in `complete` callback function, check a variable, if its value is true, then return the function. It works for me, but is there any way that I can just remove the callback function directly? Just something like `removeEventListener()`.

Can't find it by Google or on jQuery website.

Comment: have a look at the `.stop()` function in jQuery. [jQuery API: .stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: My code isn't bind to a DOM so how do I stop it?

Comment: Why are you doing it with animate, not with settimeout or setinterval?

Comment: Store your object in a variable when you create it, then you can reference it later anywhere inside of `updateCounter()`. For example: `var myObject = $({somevalue: 2*60*100}); myObject.animate({...step: function() { if (...) { myObject.stop(true,true);}},....`

Comment: @ShamSUP your answer is the correct and, why not post as answer so that I can take your answer as the accepted one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your object isn't bound to the DOM in any way, the best method is probably to store your object in a variable when you create it. This way you can access that object by the variable name whenever you need to manipulate it.

```
function updateCounter(){
    var timer = $({someValue: 2*60*1000});

    timer.animate({someValue: 0}, {
        duration: 2*60*1000,
        easing:"linear",
        step: function() {
            if(yourCondition == true){ // condition for killing timer
                // do stuff when your timer is going to end
                // stops animation, default doesn't perform complete callback
                timer.stop();
            }
            // normal step function events
        },
        complete: function() {
            // 2 minutes end
            alert('game_over');
        }
    });
}
```